# What is this python function looking for?

Tags: python, linux, bash

I have a section of python that I am banging my head up against a wall on. I am not a python developer/programmer. However, I was tasked with redoing some functionality in this application and I cannot figure out what this is looking for. I have a bash program, support.sh, that is called. It does the same thing as the old one, but I removed 500 lines of useless code. It gathers a bunch of logs and other information, and then I rsync some directories and through them into /tmp/"$bundleName" which then creates a zip.

To start the process, there is a python script that is called, and that calls my bash script. Here is the segment that checks my bash, but I have no idea what it is looking for to denote the completion of my bash program. Once I know what it's looking for to denote my bash is complete, I will add that to the end of my program to denote that it's done.

Here is the python that looks for the status of my bash:

```
def checkSupportBundleGenerationStatus(bundle):
    try:
        f=open(SUPPORT_BUNDLE_DIR + bundle + '/' + SUPPORT_BUNDLE_LOG,'r')
        blog=f.read()
        f.close()
    except:
        sendError("Invalid bundle")
    log.message(cgiutil.LOG_INFO, "Log bundle generation output so far %r bytes." % len(blog))
    filename=None
    lines = blog.splitlines()
    for l in lines:
       pair = l.split(':', 1)
       if len(pair) == 2 and pair[0] == 'File':
            filename=pair[1].strip()
            break
    blog=re.sub(r'\rPreparing Files: [-\\|/]','',blog)
    if filename:
        dlPath=filename.replace(SUPPORT_BUNDLE_DIR,'',1)
        try:
            fileSize=os.stat(filename).st_size
        except:
            sendError('Error accesing bundle zip')
        lastSlash=filename.rfind("/")
        if lastSlash != -1 :
            filename=filename[lastSlash+1:]
            dlMessage='''<form action="%s" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" value="%s"/>
%s (%s) is ready for download. <input type="submit" value="Download">
</form>''' % (
                buildGetQuery(downloadbundle=dlPath),
                os.environ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'],
                filename,
                convertBytes(fileSize)
            )
        sendBundlePage(dlMessage,blog)
    else:
        sendBundlePage(WAIT_MSG,blog,buildGetQuery(checkbundle=bundle), os.environ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any part of this code that calls a bash script.

Comment: It's looking for a line of the form `File: <filename>`. If it finds it, it runs all the code after `if filename:`, oherwise it goes into the `else` clause.

Comment: @user2357112 This code is run _after_ running the bash script, it processes the log file that the script creates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop:

```
for l in lines:
   pair = l.split(':', 1)
   if len(pair) == 2 and pair[0] == 'File':
        filename=pair[1].strip()
        break
```

Looks for the first line that begins with `File:`. It sets `filename` to the filename after that prefix. If this line is found, it will then execute the block of code after:

```
if filename:
```

If it's not found, it will go to:

```
else:
    sendBundlePage(WAIT_MSG,blog,buildGetQuery(checkbundle=bundle), os.environ['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])
```

Comment: Perfect. That gave me exactly what I needed. Apparently in the old bash program, line 160 declares $filename, which is what I ~didn't~ add to mine. I really appreciate the look into it, that solved my issue!